# how to use "this" inside a method´s local function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this method:

```
export class WebAudioApiProvider {
     private _Oscillators: OscillatorNode[] = [undefined,undefined];
    PlayOscillator(hz: number, durationInSeconds: number = 3){
        // clear the timeout (if there was one)
        clearTimeout(this._timeOutContainer);
        console.info("_activeOscillatorIndex: " + this._activeOscillatorIndex);
        switch (this._activeOscillatorIndex) {
            // There are no active oscillators
            case -1:
                prepareOscillators(0);
                break;
            case 0:
                prepareOscillators( 1, 0 ); 
                break;
            case 1:
                prepareOscillators( 0, 1 ); 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        function prepareOscillators (indexToConnect: number, indextoDispose?: number)=>{
            console.dir(this);
            var success: boolean = false;
                if (indextoDispose !== undefined && this._Oscillators[indextoDispose] !== undefined){
                    console.dir(this._Oscillators[indextoDispose]);                
                    console.log("this._Oscillators["+indextoDispose+"] is NOT undefined, it will be stoped and saved as undefined");
                    // disconnect the current oscillator
                    this._Oscillators[indextoDispose].stop();
                    this._Oscillators[indextoDispose] = undefined;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to reference this (from the class) in th the local `PlayOscillator` function, I have tried to assigned as `let PlayOscillator = (param,param) => {}` but it didn't work.

What is the correct way to do it? Do I need to put "this" as a parameter? `PlaOscillator(1, 0 , this)` ?

Comment: The `this` in `PlayOscillator` should be fine, unless you are passing this function as a callback. Are you doing that?

Comment: No, I don't think so... when I console.dir "this" i get an "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function prepareOscillators =` is a syntax error. If you're trying to use an arrow function (which would make sense here, so it closes over `this`), don't use `function`, use `const` (or `let`). You also need to move it up to *before* it's used:

```
export class WebAudioApiProvider {
    private _Oscillators: OscillatorNode[] = [undefined,undefined];
    PlayOscillator(hz: number, durationInSeconds: number = 3){
        // clear the timeout (if there was one)
        clearTimeout(this._timeOutContainer);
        const prepareOscillators = (indexToConnect: number, indextoDispose?: number)=>{
            console.dir(this);
            var success: boolean = false;
            if (indextoDispose !== undefined && this._Oscillators[indextoDispose] !== undefined){
                console.dir(this._Oscillators[indextoDispose]);                
                console.log("this._Oscillators["+indextoDispose+"] is NOT undefined, it will be stoped and saved as undefined");
                // disconnect the current oscillator
                this._Oscillators[indextoDispose].stop();
                this._Oscillators[indextoDispose] = undefined;
            }
        };
        console.info("_activeOscillatorIndex: " + this._activeOscillatorIndex);
        switch (this._activeOscillatorIndex) {
            // There are no active oscillators
            case -1:
                prepareOscillators(0);
                break;
            case 0:
                prepareOscillators( 1, 0 ); 
                break;
            case 1:
                prepareOscillators( 0, 1 ); 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `=` was a typo, I have tried put it as an arrow function and went back (ctrl+z) to paste the code here. But my error was the second thing you posted: put the function before it gets call. thanks